# Find the series solution of the following ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Find the series solution to the following ODE:
$$ y'' - x^3y' +xy = 0 $$

I couldn't find the answer, I think made a mistake to find constants. Please give me any hint or expression. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: In general let $y(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n}(x-x_0)^{n}$ if $x_0 = 0$ take the derivatives using the power rule.

Comment: In the power $x^n$ you get coefficients with indices $n+2, n-2, n-1$ with non-constant coefficients. Apart from manually computing the first 10 coefficients there is not much that you can do with that recursion.

Comment: @RyanHowe Actually I used this rule but the problem is I did not find the A0 coefficients